# Error while downloading Lists in a spweb

Tags: 2007, list, sharepoint-designer, client-object-model, spweb

Here is the code

```
private void downloadList(SPObjectData objectData)
    {
        using (SPWeb currentWeb = objectData.Web)
        {
            foreach (SPList list in currentWeb.Lists)
            {
                    foreach (SPFolder oFolder in list.Folders)
                    {
                        if (oFolder != null)
                        {
                            foreach (SPFile file in oFolder.files)
                            {
                                if (CreateDirectoryStructure(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url))
                                {
                                    var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url);
                                    byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary();
                                    System.IO.FileStream fstream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath);
                                    fstream.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
                                    fstream.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error while compilation

> Error Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder'.

Error coming on line " foreach (SPFolder oFolder in list.Folders)

I am trying to assign a folder in list. folders to folder but for some reason it giving error mentioned above.

Comment: Check this link for answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657442/error-while-downloading-lists-in-a-spweb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SPList.Folders returns the collection of SPListItem object. so we have to iterate the SPList.Items and then we have get the folder object from SPListItem.

We have to replace the following line,

```
foreach (SPFolder oFolder in list.Folders)
```

with this snippet.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.items)
{
   SPFolder oFolder = item.Folder;
   // Your code
}
```